# Next.js app - how do I pull + show the git version? - pulling github.sha (to show git version on UI) is always undefined

Tags: github, next.js, environment-variables, commit, sha

In a react app I worked on before, we would pull the github.sha from the HTML through a meta tag (also having the github.sha setup in the build files), but I'm not sure if that applies in a next.js app. Is there a different way to pull the github.sha from somewhere (correctly) and be able to display it?

I'm pulling the github version from the build files through `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_VERSION` but it's always undefined.

- from the build dev files:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_VERSION: ${{ github.sha }}
```

I was expecting the commit hash so I could display it on the UI.